# Create One Result set from 3 different Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a result set using three queries. I have three tables an inventory table, a form order table, and a form order detail table. I need to be able to input a date range and get how many forms were ordered, how many are in current inventory, and how many were destroyed based on if they contain a destruction date. Ultimately i want a result set that shows:

```
 InventoryId, FormDescription, Product, Ordered, Shipped, Destroyed, Total ending
```

What would be the best way to get that result set using these queries?

These are my three Queries

```
SELECT FOD.InventoryId, SUM(FOD.FormOrderAmount) as totalOrdered,  FOD.FormShippedAmount  FROM tblFormOrder FMO 
JOIN tblFormOrderDetails FOD ON FOD.FormOrderId = FMO.FormOrderId 
WHERE FMO.OrderDateTime BETWEEN '20110101' and '20120101' 
AND FMO.OrderStatus IN ('S')
GROUP BY FOD.InventoryId, FOD.FormShippedAmount -- total shipped by date and inventoryid



SELECT INV.InventoryId, SUM(INV.CurrentAmount) as currentAmount, SUM(INV.OrderAmount) as OrderAmount, 
(SUM(INV.OrderAmount) - SUM(INV.CurrentAmount)) as InventoryUsed
 FROM tblInventory INV
where INV.CreatedOn 
BETWEEN '20110101' and '20120101' 
GROUP BY INV.InventoryId -- current amount based off ordered and used



 select INV.InventoryId, count(*) as total
,  FMO.OrderDateTime as OrderDate, Inv.FormNo, INV.FormDescription, INV.Product 
 from [tblinventory] INV
join tblformorderdetails FOD ON FOD.InventoryId = inv.InventoryId 
join tblformorder FMO on FMO.FormOrderId = FOD.FormOrderId
where INV.DestructionDate  
BETWEEN '20110101' and '20120101' 
group by  
FMO.OrderDateTime,
 Inv.FormNo, INV.FormDescription, INV.Product, INV.InventoryId -- using count to find how many destroyed if they have a destruction date
```

Comment: Join the queries.

Comment: @Barmar that is what i am unsure of how to do.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (query1) AS q1 JOIN (query2) AS q2 ON q1.InventoryID = q2.InventoryID JOIN (query3) AS q3 ON q1.InventoryID = q3.InventoryID`

Comment: Can you post the ddl and sample data? Also, this forum is not for blindly providing you solutions for questions which is vague. Show us what you have tried and we may help.

Comment: @Barmar please post that as an answer. That is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make each query a subquery that you join together.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT FOD.InventoryId, SUM(FOD.FormOrderAmount) as totalOrdered,  FOD.FormShippedAmount  FROM tblFormOrder FMO 
    JOIN tblFormOrderDetails FOD ON FOD.FormOrderId = FMO.FormOrderId 
    WHERE FMO.OrderDateTime BETWEEN '20110101' and '20120101' 
    AND FMO.OrderStatus IN ('S')
    GROUP BY FOD.InventoryId, FOD.FormShippedAmount -- total shipped by date and inventoryid
) AS q1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT INV.InventoryId, SUM(INV.CurrentAmount) as currentAmount, SUM(INV.OrderAmount) as OrderAmount, 
    (SUM(INV.OrderAmount) - SUM(INV.CurrentAmount)) as InventoryUsed
     FROM tblInventory INV
    where INV.CreatedOn 
    BETWEEN '20110101' and '20120101' 
    GROUP BY INV.InventoryId -- current amount based off ordered and used
 ) AS q2 ON q1.InventoryId = q2.InventoryId
LEFT JOIN (
    select INV.InventoryId, count(*) as total
    ,  FMO.OrderDateTime as OrderDate, Inv.FormNo, INV.FormDescription, INV.Product 
     from [tblinventory] INV
    join tblformorderdetails FOD ON FOD.InventoryId = inv.InventoryId 
    join tblformorder FMO on FMO.FormOrderId = FOD.FormOrderId
    where INV.DestructionDate  
    BETWEEN '20110101' and '20120101' 
    group by  
    FMO.OrderDateTime,
     Inv.FormNo, INV.FormDescription, INV.Product, INV.InventoryId -- using count to find how many destroyed if they have a destruction date
) AS q3 ON q1.InventoryId = q3.InventoryId
```

Comment: Note, this might miss some items if they exits in tblinventory but not in tblformorderdetails.  Probably not an issue in this case, but can be an issue with this technique.

Comment: @Hogan Correct. Your version is probably safer in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an inner join you can do this

```
SELECT *
FROM (...) AS Q1, (...) AS Q2, (...) AS Q3
WHERE Q1.InventoryID = Q2.InventoryID AND Q2.InventoryID = Q3.InventoryID
```

This will only give you the InventoryIDs that are in all 3 queries.

You probably don't want this you probably want all inventory IDs... so you do this.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT InventoryID FROM tblFormOrderDetails 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT DISTINCT InventoryID FROM tblInventory) I
LEFT JOIN (...) Q1 ON I.InventoryID = Q1.InventoryId
LEFT JOIN (...) Q2 ON I.InventoryID = Q2.InventoryId
LEFT JOIN (...) Q3 ON I.InventoryID = Q3.InventoryId
```